# Change color of red button in edit table

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

i have searched a lot but i only find how to change the delete button. What i have to change is the color of the little rounded button. Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: try to loop through subviews and see what that button class is!

Answer (score 1):

That red button is not a button . It is a image.

You need to find for a subview in the `UITableViewCell` and when the subview is `UITableViewCellEditControl`, you cast the view as image view and you change the image in it.

You need to have a custom colored image similar to the red image.

```
for (UIView *subv in cell.subviews){
    if ([NSStringFromClass([subv class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {

                for (UIView *imgV in subv.subviews){ {

                  if(imgV isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
                    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)imgV;
                    imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"];
                    imgV.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
                     NSLog(@"subview-subview  name is %@",NSStringFromClass([imgV class]));
                }

                }

            }
}
```

[image]

Please note that changing the private subviews is not a good practise. This method may not work in the next iOS update- credits to @rmaddy.

Another work around would be to design your own custom cell.

Comment: This is dangerous, fragile code. This code assumes every subview of the `UITableViewCellEditControl` is a `UIImageView`. That's a terrible assumption that will likely cause a crash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Reading yoir code i think i have to put it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, right? Is not workig :(

Comment: @rmaddy so what is your idea?

Comment: @Quetool The code can be used but there needs to be a check to confirm that `imgV` is really a `UIImageView`. But even if you get it to work now, such code can easily stop working in some iOS update. It's never a good idea to dig into and modify the private subviews of standard controls.

Comment: @rmaddy is it ok, to check if subview is kind of class UIImageView and then change it ? I updated my answer.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri See my previous comment.

Comment: I agree with you @rmaddy. They may change the class names or they may even remove it in the next version! I will add your comment too!